# POST data to a WebAPI controller

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking to send information from a form submitted on a webpage to be processed by the WebAPI of another website. The form is basically a series of fields as follows:

1. Account Type (radio button 2 options)
2. Name
3. Email
4. Phone Number
5. Tariff (dropdown 4 options)

On the Web API controller end I have created a class called QuickSwitch which is coded as follows:

```
public class QuickSwitch
{
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string AccountType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Tariff { get; set; }
}
```

On the WebAPI controller I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMXBData([FromBody] QuickSwitch qs)
    {
        #region Customer Details
        var accountType = "";
        var name = "";
        var email = "";
        var phoneNumber = "";
        var mobileNumber = "";
        var houseNumber = "";
        var address = "";
        var town = "";
        var postcode = "";
        var county = "";

        var keypadAccountNumber = "";
        var keypadTariff = "";

        var billpayCustomerNumber = "";
        var mprnNumber = "";
        var billpayTariff = "";
        #endregion 
}
```

How can I POST the data on the webpage so that it links the fields from the form to the QuickSwitch class on the WebAPI controller end. I was then hoping to be able to sign variables as:

```
var accountType = qs.AccountType;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Ajax post with JQuery.

```
var data = {
   fullName: 'john',
   email: 'a@c.com',
   // etc.etc.
};

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost/api/mycontroller/PostMXBData',
  data: data, // your QuickSwitch object
  success: successCallbackFunction
});

function successCallbackFunction(result){
    // ok!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one big flaw with your approach on posting data using a simple form to a WebAPI endpoint: what happens after the data is posted?

If you simply create a form and POST data to your controller then your web browser will show you the response from the server, and if it is a Web API endpoint it will show you not a page but (usually) a JSON/XML response (or an empty response if you simply return a 200 status code in your controller). This is not what you want (I believe).

You have two options then:

1. POST your form to a page in the same website, and then make a server-side request to the Web API endpoint (this depends on the technology used for your web page e.g. MVC, ASP.NET Web Pages, etc.);
2. Use AJAX and send your data to the Web API endpoint in background.

For the second option, assuming you are using jQuery:

```
$('#mySubmitButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postData = {
        accountType: $('#accountTypeInput').val(),
        //etc...
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://myhost/api/MyApi",
        data: postData ,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error!');
        }
    });
});
```

In the `success` callback you may want to redirect the user to a *form submitted* page, or simply show a success message in the page (it's up to you).